# Safely Use PHP to Get Remote XML

Tags: php, xml, security

I'm trying to retrieve some remote XML from another source using PHP. I understand that you're not supposed to enable `allow_url_fopen` for security reasons, so I'm not really sure how to go about doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to use `curl` for that. If your XML is available via HTTP, first `curl` it, then feed it to the XML parser.

Comment: Is curl always available, or is it some sort of component I need to install?

Comment: In your normal environment it should be compiled in. Read up on usage at: http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php. So unless you compiled your PHP yourself or are using some very peculiar OS, it should be available.

Comment: I looked at `phpinfo();` and in the section marked `disable functions` it lists a ton of `curl` related entries. Did my host just lose a customer?

Comment: Ugh, that's just simply stupid. I could understand that they don't want arbitrary code on their hosting, but these days applications access other web resources just every other day, so really there's no reason to have it disabled. Try asking admins to enable it for you, or otherwise indeed, pick another hoster :)

Comment: I'm not even going to bother arguing with them. I'll file a complaint and let that I'm dropping them because of that. Good thing I'm still in the first 30 days ;) . Thanks for the help, I believe the code I now have will work just fine elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Allow_url_fopen isn't unsafe or scary or dangerous per se, it's just that quite often it is disabled on shared hosting for various reasons.

If you control your own hosting environment, I'd say go with it. Otherwise, use curl as suggested.

Comment: For anyone who doesn't already know, one of the most common reasons for disabling fopen url wrappers is because --without defensive coding specifically against such attacks-- it automatically turns a relatively innoffensive local file inclusion vulnerability into an extremely serious arbitrary code execution vulnerability.

Comment: @Cheekysoft I know, but the only sensible solution to that is not to pass any user supplied variables into any function without checking and/or escaping the data properly first. Simply calling `$remoteXml = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/feed.xml');` cannot do any harm that couldn't be done using CURL or the like. CURL is more flexible (setting the user agent for example), but not absolutely required.

Comment: Naturally. Also the direct HTTP functions are very useful http://php.net/manual/en/ref.http.php